# Transforming functions by moving both $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have become aware that in some high school curricula they are teaching the following method to "transform a point on a function":

Say $f(x) = 2x^2 + 2$ is the original function and $g(x) = 3f(x-2)$ is the transformed function.  A common homework problem is of the form "given the two functions, where does the point $(1,4)$ end up after it is transformed by $g(x)$?"

Students are required to first map $1 \rightarrow 1-2 = -1$, then to map $f(1) \rightarrow 3*f(1-2) = 3f(-1) = 12$.  The "correct" answer, then, is that $(1,2)$ maps to $(-1,12)$.

I have a significant issue with this, in that the mapping is moving both $x$ and $y$.  $y$ ends up as I would expect - transformed under the function.  But the function doesn't transform $x$, which should be independent.  What are they trying to get at with these types of questions?

Comment: I think these questions are getting at is learning to think about translation and scaling on the $x$ and $y$ axes. The former is "inside" the function, the latter "outside". But teaching this a a rule or "method" may turn it into yet another algorithm to be applied without thought.

Comment: That does make sense, but the way the questions are often asked implies that the function moves both coordinates.  I wonder if there was any mathematical reason for ever doing this?  I can see it being relevant if there were a parameterization, where $x = x(t)$ and $y = y(t)$, but then we're just transforming two functions in the more reasonable way

Comment: Maybe the problem here is that (1,4) actually maps to (3,12)?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean.  The function, so far as I can tell, only maps the $y$ - for the same $x$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will have different values.  That, as I have understood things, is the point of saying that $f$ and $g$ are different...

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$g(x)=3f(x-2)=3(2(x-2)^2+2)=3(2(x^2-4x+4)+2)=3(2x^2-8x+8+2)$$
$$=3(2x^2-8x+10)=6x^2-24x+30.$$
Therefore, $g(-1)=6-24+30=12,$ as required. The point is on the new function.

Comment: Oops, you are right.  I've edited the question to reflect that the confusion stems from the fact that $x$ is independent and thus not transformed, which is actually what I was concerned about

Comment: $g(-1)=6-24+30=12$, really? Or: $g(-1)=6-(-24)+30=60$?